# Cart in FastSpring is automatically empty after user closes popup StoreFront

Tags: reactjs, api

I'm integrating FastSpring into my app for payment, and I have problem with keeping data in cart after closing popup storefront.

According to documentation I pasted script in my index.html like this

```
  <script
    id="fsc-api"
    src="https://d1f8f9xcsvx3ha.cloudfront.net/sbl/0.8.3/fastspring-builder.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"
    data-storefront="xxxxx.test.onfastspring.com/popup-xxx"
    data-popup-webhook-received='paymentReceived'>
</script>
```

Then in my React app in js file I made, several buttons for adding to cart products and one for showing cart

```
     <Buy onClick={()=>{addToCart(licence.name.replace(/\s+/g, ''))}}> <AddShoppingCartIcon/>Add to cart</Buy>
     <ShoppingCartIcon onClick={()=>{myCart()}} style={{ width:'35px', height:'35px', cursor:'pointer'}}/>
```

These are my functions for showing and adding to cart

```
     async function myCart () {
             let res
            try {
               res= await window.fastspring.builder.viewCart()
            }
            catch(err) {
                console.log('err',err)
    
            }
            if(!res) { //res is always undefined (when cart is empty and also when its not)
                NotificationManager.error('Your cart is empty! Please add some products.')
            }
    
        }
        function addToCart (productID) {
 
            const res= window.fastspring.builder.add(productID)
            NotificationManager.success('Product added to your cart.')
        }
```

The problem is: If there is something in cart after closing popup StoreFront cart is automatically empty if you try to show it again.
It shows this error

> [FastSpring API] (!) Error: Error received:  400 empty-session

How to keep data in cart after closing popup storefront?
Anyone had similar problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a late answer, but I had the same case when the cart was clearing after closing a popup. Fortunately, FastSpring has an option `continuous`, which prevents clearing the cart after closing a popup. Just add `data-continuous="true"` to your `script` tag. I have dug in FastSpring's JavaScript SDK and debugged the whole cycle to discover that option.

Docs: https://fastspringexamples.com/callback/data-continuous/